# Using XMLDecoder.createHandler() returned handler to parse embedded xml-persisted java objects

Tags: java, javabeans

In the doc of XMLDecoder.createHandler():

```
"
     * Creates a new handler for SAX parser
     * that can be used to parse embedded XML archives
     * created by the {@code XMLEncoder} class.
..."
```

But `createHandler()` returns an object of  `DefaultHandler` type ... what's the utility of this ?

I need to parse objects embedded in a heterogeneus xml file using `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser` and I'm trying to avoid the import of `com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have this question as well, and would be very interested in any answers you may have come across.  In the mean time the best that I have come up with is:

```
DefaultHander handler = XMLDecoder.createHandler( ... );
SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().parse(in, handler);
Object[] data = (Object[])decoderHandler.getClass().getMethod("getObjects").invoke(decoderHandler);
```

Clearly this is not ideal, but it does the job within the constraints that we have been allowed by the API.

PS My reason for wanting to do this and not just use XMLDecoder.readObject() is because I need to intercept and potentially manipulate the XML during decoding.